# C++ constant instance using a protected constructor?

Tags: c++, constants, instance, protected

I need to define a C++ class that generate unique identifiers. The idea is that every instance of every visible class will be tagged by a unique integer value. Let's call that the "handle" of the instance. The handles must be unique across all the instances in the system.

Some instances may be related to other ones, in which case their class defines a member to store the handle of their relative.

But not all instances actually have a relative. So I need a special handle value to stand for an "undefined" relative.

I need help to define that special instance. Here is what I tried:

```
class Handle {
public:
  Handle(): mValue(newValue()) {};

  static const Handle kUndefHandle(0);         // (1)

protected:
  Handle(int val): mValue(val) {};             // (2)
  int mValue;
  static int mNextValue = 1000; // start at 1000. (3)

  static int newValue() { return mNextValue++; }
};
```

Notes:

- line (3) doesn't compile (Clang 3.x). The compiler refuses the inline initialization of the static variable. The fix is easy, initialize it offline in an implementation file. So my class cannot be header-only, but I can live with that.
- line (1) defines my special constant instance. Unfortunately, the compiler fails, saying "Expected parameter declarator".

I also tried: `static const Handle kUndefHandle = 0;` but then the compiler complains "Variable has incomplete type 'Handle'", *even if I put it in a subclass*. And I can't reopen a class in C++ like in Ruby.

I can sort of make it work by putting that const instance declaration outside of the class. I lose the class scope, but that's a minor drawback. I can still use a namespace if I care.

However this only works if I make the constructor in line (2) public. And I don't want that. I don't want to let the programmer construct handles with arbitrary values.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The usual way to provide a handle to an object is to use its pointer value, which is guaranteed to be unique. The "unset" value is naturally NULL. Have you thought about that?

Comment: Sure I have. But these values are visible in files and must be transmittable across files/machines/network. I feel uncomfortable using pointers that way. This also creates headache when pointer sizes differ across machines. (yes `int` is a bad choice from that respect too. the actual integral type I use is better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

## Header

```
class Handle {
public:
  Handle(): mValue(newValue()) {};

  static const Handle kUndefHandle;

protected:
  Handle(int val): mValue(val) {};
  int mValue;
  static int mNextValue;

  static int newValue() { return mNextValue++; }
};
```

## Implementation

```
const Handle Handle::kUndefHandle(0);

int Handle::mNextValue = 1000;
```

Initializing a static class member is actually considered to be within the scope of the class, so you can access private and protected constructors in that context.

---

Note that you should make the constructor private, because **there currently exists a loophole by which people could construct handles with arbitrary values**: derive the class, chain to the protected constructor, then convert the resultant object to `Handle`.  ([See an example on ideone](http://ideone.com/Q9bg3))

```
class FakeHandle : public Handle
{
public:
  FakeHandle(int val) : Handle(val) { }
};
```

Now one could do:

```
Handle badHandle = FakeHandle(5);
```

Comment: +1 The loophole is even worse, not only does it allow ill intentioned code to break the contract of handles being unique, but it also allows erroneous code to do it. Additionally, because there is no explicit copy constructor or assignment operators at the `Handle` level, copies of an object will all share the handle value (which is probably unwanted)

Answer (score 0):

`static const` members can be initialized inside the class only if they are of integral type. That is a special case, the general rule is that you have to put the initialization in the .cpp file (along with your static non-const).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeleton to get you started:

```
class Foo
{
    static int const undef_handle;
    static int next_handle;
    static int get_handle() { return ++next_handle; }

    int const my_handle;
    int const related_handle;

public:

    Foo()
    : my_handle(get_handle())
    , related_handle(undef_handle)
    { }

    Foo(int h)
    : my_handle(get_handle())
    , related_handle(h)
    { }

    // Copy/move constructors, assignment, ...
};

int Foo::next_handle = 1000;
int const Foo::undef_handle = 0;
```